# Dreampie Python Interpreter Documentaion

Tags: python, idle-python

Where can I find documentation/user-guide/tutorial for using Dreampie Python Interpreter? There is nothing in the man-page.

Answer (score 1):

From [the Github issues page](https://github.com/noamraph/dreampie/issues/24#issuecomment-14346181):

> There's no real documentation, but you can find the important staff under Help->Getting Started.

Comment: But getting started only have very things.How do I clear console in dreampie. Please add basic commands in your answer if possible

Comment: From where? If the developer themselves won't do it, how would I document it with any degree of certainty? Maybe you should consider filing a bug report (but I don't expect much to happen: https://github.com/noamraph/dreampie/issues/65)